# Angularjs RSS Reader - preload rss feed

Tags: angularjs, rss

got this script to read some RSS feeds. It works fine when I click the links

```
<a href="#" ng-click="feedSrc='http://feeds.feedburner.com/TechCrunch';loadFeed($event);">TechCrunch</a>
```

But I would like **to load the result of the first feed directly when the page loads**

Appreciate some help.
[Example here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rxOoNV)

HTML:

```
<div data-ng-controller="FeedCtrl" ng-app="RSSFeedApp">

  <p>
    <a href="#" ng-click="feedSrc='http://feeds.feedburner.com/TechCrunch';loadFeed($event);">TechCrunch</a> |
    <a href="#" ng-click="feedSrc='http://rss.cnn.com/rss/cnn_topstories.rss';loadFeed($event);">CNN</a>
  </p>

  <ul class="unstyled">
    <li ng-repeat="feed in feeds | filter:filterText">
      <h5><a href="{{feed.link}}">{{feed.title}}</a></h5>
      <p class="date">{{feed.publishedDate | date : format : timezone}}</p>
    </li>
  </ul>

</div>
```

JS:

```
var App = angular.module('RSSFeedApp', []);

App.controller("FeedCtrl", ['$scope', 'FeedService', function($scope, Feed) {

  $scope.loadFeed = function(e) {
    Feed.parseFeed($scope.feedSrc).then(function(res) {
      $scope.feeds = res.data.responseData.feed.entries;
    });

  }
}]);

App.factory('FeedService', ['$http', function($http) {
  return {
    parseFeed: function(url) {

      return $http.jsonp('//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=1.0&num=5&callback=JSON_CALLBACK&q=' + encodeURIComponent(url));
    }
  }
}]);
```

Answer (score 1):

it was great to find your code, so I decided to pay you back:

```
<div data-ng-controller="FeedCtrl" ng-app="RSSFeedApp" ng-init="feedSrc='http://feeds.feedburner.com/TechCrunch';loadFeed($event);">

  <p>
    <a href="#" ng-click="feedSrc='http://feeds.feedburner.com/TechCrunch';loadFeed($event);">TechCrunch</a> |
    <a href="#" ng-click="feedSrc='http://rss.cnn.com/rss/cnn_topstories.rss';loadFeed($event);">CNN</a>
  </p>

  <ul class="unstyled">
    <li ng-repeat="feed in feeds | filter:filterText">
      <h5><a href="{{feed.link}}">{{feed.title}}</a></h5>
      <p class="date">{{feed.publishedDate | date : format : timezone}}</p>
    </li>
  </ul>

</div>
```